# Can't pass `json` string to `sh` step in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to retag a docker image on Amazon ECR using the [awscli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/retag-aws-cli.html) but when I pass the json string to the `sh` step I get the error `Invalid JSON syntax`. When I log the json string the double quotes around the keys and values are not there. I'm assuming [groovy's string interpolation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation) rules are stripping the quotes? The code below mirrors the [awscli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/retag-aws-cli.html) docs with the `sh` step wrapping each command.

```
script {
    MANIFEST = sh(
           returnStdout: true,
           script: "aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name amazonlinux --image-ids imageTag=latest --query images[].imageManifest --output text"
    ).trim()
    sh """ aws ecr put-image --repository-name amazonlinux --image-tag 2017.03 --image-manifest \\"$MANIFEST\\" """
}
```

The error returned

```
[test] Running shell script
+ aws ecr put-image --repository-name amazonlinux --image-tag 2017.03 --image-manifest "{

An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the PutImage operation: Invalid parameter at 'ImageManifest' failed to satisfy constraint: 'Invalid JSON syntax'
```

I've tried using the `groovy.json.JsonOutput` but no luck. It prints the string with quotes escaped and new line characters `{\n   \"schemaVersion\": 2,\n   \"mediaType\": ...`

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
...
script {
    def MANIFEST = sh(
           returnStdout: true,
           script: "aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name amazonlinux --image-ids imageTag=latest --query images[].imageManifest --output text"
    ).trim()
    def json = JsonOutput.toJson(MANIFEST)
    echo JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json)
    sh """ aws ecr put-image --repository-name amazonlinux --image-tag 2017.03 --image-manifest \\"$json\\" """
}
```

[edit] Just noticed if I change the last line to `returnStdout` it shows the command as `aws ecr put-image --repository-name amazonlinux --image-tag 2017.03 --image-manifest "{\n   "schemaVersion": 2,\n   "mediaType": ...` which means the quotes in the JsonOutput is working but its adding new lines? Going to try to remove the new lines and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Yes quotes are silently dropped . You can refer to this page ,it shows escaping of characters in a very elaborate way :
https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4

Answer (score 2):

Following solution works:

```
MANIFEST= sh( script:"(aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name ${ECRNAME} --image-ids imageTag=${IMAGE} --query 'images[0].imageManifest' --output json)",returnStdout: true)
MANIFEST1 = "${MANIFEST}".replace('\\n', '')
sh( script:"aws ecr put-image --repository-name ${ECRNAME} --image-tag ${env.RELEASE_SCOPE}_latest --image-manifest ${MANIFEST1}",returnStdout: true)
```

Notice: I have used `--output json` and then replaced `'\n'` from json.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this exact same issue and ended up using a shell script to handle the AWS ECR tagging. Tried various combinations of quotes, escaping, even tried changing the return type of the batch-get-image query to JSON. Once it's passed to the put-image command, either returned the Invalid JSON Syntax error or ended up creating a duplicate image in ECR with the new tag.

Here's the shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh 

repo=$1
tag=$2
tag_as=$3

MANIFEST=$(aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name $1 --image-ids imageTag=$2 --query images[].imageManifest --output text)

aws ecr put-image --repository-name $1 --image-tag $3 --image-manifest "$MANIFEST"
```

In Jenkins:

```
result = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "./retag.sh ${REPO_NAME} ${TAG} ${TAG_AS}")
```

Answer (score 0):

This code block working fine.

```
    sh '''
        $(aws ecr get-login --region your_region)
        MY_MANIFEST=$(aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name repo_name --image-ids imageTag='''+ tag +''' --region your_region --query images[].imageManifest --output text)
        aws ecr put-image --repository-name repo_name --image-tag latest --image-manifest "$MY_MANIFEST" --region your_region
        '''
```

aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.9